# ArrayList will not use .get(int) for subclass objects in list, but will allow me to use .add()

Tags: java, oop, arraylist, subclass, superclass

I have a class

```
public abstract class superObject{}
```

and subclasses

```
public class subObj1 extends superObject{}

public class subObj2 extends superObject{}
```

In my main class I have

```
List<superObject> aList = new ArrayList<>();
```

of which will allow me to invoke

```
aList.add(subObj1)
```

but I cannot invoke

```
aList.get(0)
```

becuase for any object in the Array list that isn't of type superObject the compilier says I'm trying to return incompatiable types.

And I'm completely baffeled as to why?

edit: example code was incorrect

Comment: Remove the parentheses from `extends superObject(){}`, maybe? Does that even compile? Should be `extends superObject {}` but consider following the Java naming conventions by making class names start with a capital letter. By the way... What is the exact error message?

Comment: From which method are you invoking `alist.get(0)`

Comment: In the line ```aList.add(subObj1)``` what is subObj1 here? If it's just an instance of the class subObj1 then the code is fine, I dont get any error when calling ```aList.get(0)```

Comment: https://onlinegdb.com/HkRzdu0h8